# Getting Odd numbers from Array

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I've been working on this program and am currently stuck. The HW prompt is to prompt a user to input numbers, save it as an array, find the number of odd numbers & the percentages then display those values back to the user.

Currently I am trying to write to part of the code that finds the percentage of the odd numbers in the array but the return isn't displaying and i just cant figure it out. Any ideas? Thank you!

```
import java.util.*; // import java course for Scanner class
public class Integers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input a series of numbers");
        int inputs = Integer.parseInt(console.next());
        int[] arraysize = new int[inputs];
        Oddvalues(arraysize);
    }

    public static int Oddvalues (int[] size) {
        int countOdd = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < size.length; i++) {
            if(size[i] % 2 != 0) {
                i++;
            }
        }
        return countOdd;    
    }

}
```

Comment: you are not adding any data to the array

Comment: Arrays start at `0` not `1`. You increment `i`, instead of `countOdd`.

Comment: I presume HW =  HomeWork?   Question for you.  What value is returned from the Oddvalues function?

Comment: You are not increassing the value of `countOdd` in `Oddvalues()`. When you returned the percentage of odd numbers then store it in some variable in `main` function and do `System.out.print()` after that. Or call the Oddvalues in main like `System.out.println(Oddvalues(arraysize));`

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code, which appears to be working in IntelliJ locally.  My approach is to read in a single line from the scanner as a string, and then to split that input by whitespace into component numbers.  This avoids the issue you were facing of trying to directly create an array of integers from the console.

Then, just iterate over each numerical string, using `Integer.parseInt()`, checking to see if it be odd.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input a series of numbers");
    String nextLine = console.nextLine();
    String[] nums = nextLine.split(" ");
    int oddCount = 0;
    for (String num : nums) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(num) % 2 == 1) {
            ++oddCount;
        }
    }
    double oddPercent = 100.0*oddCount / nums.length;
    System.out.println("Total count of numbers: " + nums.length + ", percentage odd: " + oddPercent);
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why tested functioning code should be downvoted?

Comment: Why not do their entire homework assignment for them, will you?  And, but doing their homework, what exactly do you think they are learning?

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with this answer.  It suggests reading in a single line of numbers, splitting, then taking a tally.  No helper methods needed.

Comment: There are at least five or more troubles with the original posting. The original poster is doing a homework assignment in Java, and doesn't remotely understand the basic concepts.   What they've learned now is 1) whine, and 2)  somebody will do their homework for them.  Copy the code from the stack and turn in the homework.  Question, would you want this person to be teamed up with you at your next job? Why not?

Comment: @zipzit Perhaps 95% of questions I see and answer on SO fit this description.  The OP _has_ shown effort, and the code isn't completely wrong, though not completely working either.

Answer (score 0):

In the function Oddvalues you promote i instead of promoting countOdd. And the loop should start from 0 not 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
public class OddVals{
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] array = new int[sc.nextInt()];        // Get the value of each element in the array
    System.out.println("Please input a series of numbers");
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        array[i] = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Number of Odds:" +Oddvalues(array));
    printOdd(array);
    }
public static int Oddvalues (int[] size) {
    int countOdd = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < size.length; i++){
        if(size[i]%2 != 0)
         ++countOdd;            
    }
    return countOdd;    
    }
public static void printOdd(int[] arr)
{
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;++i)
    {
        if(arr[i]%2==1)
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*; // import java course for Scanner class
public class Integers {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();


        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input a series of numbers");
        while (console.hasNext())
        {

            String str = console.next();
            try
            {
                if(str.equals("quit")){
                    break;
                }
                int inputs = Integer.parseInt(str);

                System.out.println("the integer values are" +inputs);
                intList.add(inputs);
            }
            catch (java.util.InputMismatchException|NumberFormatException e)
            {
                console.nextLine();
            }


        }
        console.close();
        double d = Oddvalues(intList);
        System.out.println("the percent is" +d);
    }

    public static double Oddvalues (List<Integer> list) {
        int count = 0;
        for( Integer i : list)
        {

            if(!(i%2==0))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        double percentage = (Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(count))/ Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(list.size())))*100;

        return percentage; 

    }
}
```

If this helps